# Alexa sdk ask prompt

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have a scenario where customer ask Alexa what's my travel plan which is map to "TravelIntent". This intent fetches customer travel details from REST API and found that customer is having more than 1 travel plan. Now I am  prompting user that i can see that there are more than 1 plan. Say 1 for weekend trip , say 2 for blah blah... etc.Now when user responds by saying 2 Alexa can present user that your trip for next week is for Delhi and  so on.. Now question is do I have to query rest api for detail or is there any way where i can persist data within Alexa session and how do it use "ask" response from the user because already "TravelIntent" has received the data from rest api.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, first you can get user's response by making slots in intent like,

```
{
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "Plan",
          "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
        }
      ],
      "intent": "TravelIntent"
}
```

From doing this you will get Plan number and you can get it by,

> var planNumber = event.request.intent.slots.Plan.value;

and query response accordingly.

Now you can persist your data by making modules and get that whenever you want. Like this,

```
var dataModule = function(){};

dataModule.prototype.setData = function(data){
    this.data = data;
}

dataModule.prototype.getData = function(data){
    return this.data;
}

module.exports = new dataModule();
```

and require it where you want data by just one line,

> var data = require('./dataModule');

Now, you can use data object to get your data.